# How to get tooltip for each row while using data table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
function addRow(tableID) 
{
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 10){                      
        // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

        }
    }
    else
    {
         alert("Allowed maximum items per indent is 10. Please raise one more indent if required");

    }
}
```

I am using Bootstrap tooltip function as below and want to get the tooltip for each row.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add following attributes according to bootstrap tooltip documentation, [Bootstrap Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Your updated code,

```
function addRow(tableID) 
{
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 10){                      
        // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }

        // tooltip code

        var datatoggle =  document.createAttribute("data-toggle");
        datatoggle.value = "tooltip" ;      
        row.setAttributeNode( datatoggle );

        var title = document.createAttribute("title");
        title.value = "< Tooltip Message >"; // you can change tooltip text here
        row.setAttributeNode( title );


        // re-instantiate tooltip after the new ones are added since there is no eventhandler attached to them. 
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    }
    else
    {
         alert("Allowed maximum items per indent is 10. Please raise one more indent if required");

    }
}
```

Comment: No its not working and not giving any error also, page is working as early

Comment: Is it possible to call tooltip function to each row ?

Comment: Actually you need to reinstantiate tooltips to attach event handlers to the new rows that are added. I have updated the code. Does it work now?

Comment: tool tip is working but it started adding  two rows at a time side by side

Comment: I just replaced the code after newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML; this line and it is functioning fine as I expected

Comment: Will u please remove title.value = "this is a tooltip"; line and put the code after newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML; so other people also get the benefit , thanks much

Comment: No sir, you I added your code after line 20 (newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;)

Comment: and removed datatoggle.value = "tooltip" ; and title.value = "< Tooltip Message >"; // you can change tooltip text here

Comment: Oops what was i thinking! Why did you not use value?

Comment: When I use value it is repeating the Tooltip twice So I removed

Answer (score 0):

```
    function addRow(tableID)
    {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
if(rowCount < 10){                      
    // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;


            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

        // tooltip code for each row
        var datatoggle =  document.createAttribute("data-toggle");
   // datatoggle.value = "tooltip" ;      

    var title = document.createAttribute("title");
    //title.value = "this is a tooltip"; // you can change tooltip text here


    row.setAttributeNode( datatoggle );
    row.setAttributeNode( title );

    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

    }

    // re-instantiate tooltip after the new ones are added since there is no eventhandler attached to them. (calling tooltip function here)
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();     

    }
}
else
{
     alert("Allowed maximum items per indent is 10. Please raise one more indent if required");

}
```

}

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try 
        {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) 
                {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) 
            {
                if(rowCount <= 1) 
                {                       // limit the user from removing all the fields
            alert("Cannot remove all rows.");
            break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
                }
        }
        catch(e) 
            {
        alert(e);
            }
    }
```

This is a final code based on @krishnaio s Answer I figured it out and marked as accepted

Comment: This code will carry all the functions whatever you added into first row.